# Python in ArcGIS environment

Tags: python, arcgis

I am a beginner at Python and am working within the ArcGIS environment..specifically working inside an attribute table (i.e. field calculator).

I have over 200 entries in this database. A field within this table (FULLNAME) lists a bunch of roads, but "road" is spelled in 4 different ways (i.e. "ROAD", "RD", "Rd", "Road").

I am trying to figure out a way to use Python within the ArcGIS field calculator to copy over the road names from the FULLNAME field into another field called FULLNAME2 while also standardizing the spelling of "road" for all entries to be "Road".

So for example, Gilman Valley Rd should be Gilman Valley Road; Center Creek ROAD should be Center Creek Road; and Schoepps Valley RD should be Schoepps Valley Road.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    def fullNameRoad(x):
  if "ROAD" in x:
    return x[:-5] + "Road"
  elif "Rd" in x:
    return x[:-2] + "Road"
  elif "RD" in x:
    return x[:-2] + "Road"
  else:
    return !FULLNAME!

FULLNAME = fullNameRoad(!FULLNAME!)
```

Any and all advice would be helpful!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If the format of your field values is [HOUSENUM] [STREETNAME] [RD/Rd/ROAD] (or just [STREETNAME] [RD/Rd/ROAD]) then it would be much less verbose to just trim any trailing whitespace and then rpartition to extract everything before the 'Road' text. No codeblock needed...

```
str( !FULLNAME!.rstrip() ).rpartition(' ')[0] + ' Road'
```